# LINQ: Consulta GROUP BY condicional COUNT

Tags: entity-framework, linq, group-by

Como es posible trasladar a `Linq` este tipo de operaciones...
en SQL:

> COUNT(CASE WHEN VALOR = "EJEMPLO" then 1 else = 0 END)

Dentro de una sentencia GROUP BY

En linq?

```
from
join...
from...
group new
{
    contador = tabla.Count(x=> x.VALOR =="EJEMPLO")
} into g
select new
{
    contador = g.Key.contador
}
```

**Actualizo**: parece correcto pero los detalles de la excepción:

> The nested query is not supported. Operation1='GroupBy'
>   Operation2='MultiStreamNest

Comment: Igual no se mucho de LINQ y cuando no se como hacer este tipo de consultas lo que hago para solucionarlo rápido es crear una vista desde SQL y ya solo llamo con un select normal.

Comment: es por optimizar y no utilizar subconsultas, además de tener todo integrado en código :)